# Difference in allocating char type and int type in C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a class `foo` like this:

```
class foo
{
private:
    int* a;
public:
    foo()
    {
        a = new int[4];
        cout << "a" << endl;
    }
};
```

When I create new object named `foo1` and then I debug, after the allocating line, it yields the result:      
 `a   0x005a4580 {-842150451}`. 
But when I replace all `int`-s by `char`-s in class definition, it yields an undesired result:

```
a   0x005694a0 "ÍÍÍÍýýýý\x6ŒÒ•\x5Ÿ"
```

that the size of `a` is now greater than 4. 
I dont know what happened. Could you please give me an explanation?

---

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class String
{
public:
    String(char* data)
    {
        setSize(0);
        while (*(data + size) != '\0')
            size++;
        this->data = new char[size];
        //need to allocate memory for 'data' pointer because 'data' pointer is now on the stack and the data must be on the heap 
        memcpy(this->data, data, size * sizeof(char));
    }
    void operator=(String rhs)
    {
        if (this->data != NULL)
            delete[] this->data, data = NULL;
        this->data = new char[rhs.getSize()]; //allocate
        memcpy(this->data, data, size * sizeof(char));
    }
    int getSize()
    {
        setSize(0);
        while (*(data + size))
            size++;
        return size;
    }
    void setSize(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
    }
    void display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << *(data + i);
    }
    ~String()
    {
        if (data != NULL)
            delete[] data, data = NULL;
    }
private:
    char* data;
    int size;
};

void main()
{
    String a("abcd");
    String b("1");
    a.display();
    cout << endl;
    cout << b.getSize() << endl;
    a = b;
    cout << a.getSize() << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This code does not match your problem statement. In addition what is "char -s"?

Comment: @user3344003 The plural of `char`.

Comment: cout<< "a" << endl ; should just print "a".

Comment: @user3344003 It probably does.

Comment: Show the code that is giving the unexpected behaviour

Comment: check out <a href="https://ideone.com/fbrmnz">my code</a> for the evidence. The size of object `a` and object `b` is different from 1.

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `main` must return `int`.

Comment: Why are you writing your own string class (which AFAICS has a broken copy constructor)?

Comment: I am running this code in Visual Studio, it is running finely. That's my homework: Re-implement the `string` class in STD library.

Comment: Why did I get too many '-'s? Poor me, asking a question and get spurned. I think SOF is the place for everyone to learn from each other?

Comment: @NguyễnTrọng -- *it is running finely.* --  Do you think so?  `{String s1("abc"); String s2 = s1;}`  -- I just broke your "running" code.  And why does `getSize()` need to iterate through the entire string to get the size?  Why not simply return `size`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: no, I mean the compiler does not blame of `void main`

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're using to look at `a` doesn't know how much you allocated. It just knows the type.

In the first version it sees `int *`, so it shows a single `int`.

In the second version it sees `char *`, so it assumes it's a C string and prints whatever is in memory up to the first `'\0'` byte.

Comment: As you say, we dont know the size of `a` `char`? By the way, is there anyway to delimit the size of `a` `char`?

Comment: @NguyễnTrọng I don't understand what you're asking. The size of a `char` is 1 by definition.